# Need a database to use with a .NET application without installation

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms

We are creating an accounting type application and need to know some options for a database to use without having to have the user install a database. I know there are some ways to do this but I would like some opinions on the best way to go and where to find more information about this.

Comment: What options do you want to know? Or are you looking for a database to use which doesn't require installation?

Comment: We are wanting a database that doesn't require installation. Our user is not extremely computer savvy and we want to make sure that they don't go deleting anything that they are not sure what is but our application requires. We are looking for the best option to use. This database is nothing that the user will need to see, just something for our application to utilize. When the run the program it will pull data from the database and present it in a more user friendly manner.

Answer (score 4):

There are two pretty viable options:

1. SQLite
2. SQL CE

Both of these options are *file based* and they have fully functional ADO.NET API's.

Comment: I've had a lot of success with SQLite.  System.Data.SQLite is the .NET wrapper.  And the license is very permissive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check out VistaDB. We have been using this db for 4-5 years at our company, and it serves our purpose. You do not have to install any software during deployment. All of your data will sit inside of .vdb3 file. The feature i like the most is "Pack" that will re-index your data, save file size and keep the performance high. You can do this from code also. They are supporting Entity Frameworks in new versions. Their sample codes are useful, and you can start coding in no time. Online support is great too.

Answer (score 0):

Without anything you can right away start with using [`OleDB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452.aspx) (example is terrible, but its MSDN) and MS Access (mdb) database.

Create database (using ADOX)

```
Type typeAdox = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ADOX.Catalog");
object objAdox = Activator.CreateInstance(typeAdox);
typeAdox.InvokeMember("Create", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objAdox, new object[] { "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file });
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objAdox);
```

Create a table

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE trololol (id datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, blob longbinary)", connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server LocalDB ([announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)), compatible with .NET and EF.

Requires a small msi to be run as installation, but that can be quitely bundled with the installation of your application (or it can do it on first run for example.)